# How to use a self-signed certificate in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, openssl, ssl-certificate, self-signed-certificate

I followed this tutorial for creating a self-signed certificate https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-18-04.
Now I have 2 new files a .crt and a .key.
How can I use these files to allow my android application to reach my server with https calls?

Comment: You need to manually install the certificate to the phone.

Comment: Your link is BS. Certificates do not encrypt data. The private key is not used to encrypt data. The only issue is that self-signed certificates aren't trusted, and you have to solve that by importing them to all clients, not only initially but every time they expire. It isn't worth the trouble. Get them signed by a CA. It is now free.